# Storing Data from both POST variables and GET parameters

Tags: python, forms, post, cgi, get

I want my python script to simultaneously accept POST variables and query string variables from the web address.

The script has code :

```
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
print form
```

However, this only captures the post variables and no query variables from the web address. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks,

Ali

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[cgi.parse_qsl](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0978739213) (in any Python `2.*`; [urlparse.parse_qsl](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.parse_qsl) in 2.6 or better) take a query string and return a list of `name, value` pairs.  Use `os.environ['QUERY_STRING']` to get the query string part of the URL your CGI script was reached at (everything after the `?` in the URL, if any).